# How can I specify a generic type on an overloaded operator in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, operator-overloading, operators

I'm looking to overload the division operator, "/", but would like to allow for a generic type to be specified to guide the type of the return value.

Here's an example:

```
inline operator fun <reified T> MyType.div(fieldName: String): T {
    val value = someFunction(fieldName) 
    return convertToExpectedValue(value)
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to explicitly specify the generic type T when it cannot be inferred. I'm wondering if there's anything like the following that would work?

```
val stringVal = myType /<MyType> "myField" /<String> "myStringField"
```

Note that I know that

```
myType.div<String>("blah")
```

works. I'm looking for something that uses the operator "/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use an intermediate variable, or (with Kotlin 1.2) `as`:

```
val midVal: MyType = myType / "myField"
val stringVal: String = midVal / "myStringField"

// or with Kotlin 1.2
// I'm not 100% sure about this one actually, so take this with a grain of salt

val stringVal = ((myType / "myField") as MyType / "myStringField") as String
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the answer is ultimately that it cannot be done.

I decided to go with overriding () so I could get the generic type. I also added a version without the generic that explicitly returns "MyType" so that chaining the calls would work with a generic type only needed at the end.

So now it looks like:

```
val stringVal = myType("fieldName")<String>("myStringField")
```

with the function definition code as:

```
inline operator fun <reified T> MyType.invoke(fieldName: String): T {
    val value = someFunction(fieldName) 
    return convertToExpectedValue(value)
}

operator fun MyType.invoke(fieldName: String): MyType {
    return someFunction(fieldName) as MyType
}
```